# Movie to another Screen in React Native Tab View

Tags: reactjs, react-native, view, tabs, native

I only want to navigate to my other screen "MycoursesPage2 from my page MycoursesPage
This is the actual code. it is giving an error on onpress function that "undefined is an object (evaluating navigation.navigate)"

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Image, Dimensions, ScrollView, StatusBar, Text } from 'react-native';
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-native-safe-area-context";
import CustomHeader from "../../components/CustomHeader";
import { IMAGE } from "../../constants/Images";
import { TabView, SceneMap, TabBar } from 'react-native-tab-view';
import * as Progress from 'react-native-progress';


const FirstRoute = ({navigation}) => (   
  <ScrollView> 
  <View style={[styles.scene, { backgroundColor: '#f7f7f7' }]} />
            
  </ScrollView>      
);    
 
function SecondRoute({ navigation }) {       
  return (
  <ScrollView>
  <View style={[styles.scene, { backgroundColor: '#f7f7f7' }]} />
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Register")}>
    
              <View
                style={{
                  borderWidth: 1,
                  borderColor: "#fff",
                  backgroundColor:'#fff',
                  borderRadius: 10,
                  padding: 15,
                  marginHorizontal:20,
                  marginVertical: 15,
                  display:'flex',
                  flexDirection:'row'
                }}
              >
                <Image
                  source={IMAGE.MYCOURSES3}
                  style={{ width: 60, height: 60 }}
                />
                <View>
                          
                <Text style={{fontSize:17, fontWeight:'bold', marginHorizontal:15}}>3D Design Illustration</Text>
                <Text style={{fontSize:14, color:'grey', marginHorizontal:15}}>2hrs 25mins</Text>
                               
              <Progress.Bar style={{marginHorizontal:15, marginVertical:5}} progress={1} width={200} />
              </View>
              
              </View>  
             
   </TouchableOpacity>
  <TouchableOpacity>
    
    <View
      style={{
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: "#fff",
        backgroundColor:'#fff',
        borderRadius: 10,
        padding: 15,
        marginHorizontal:20,
        display:'flex',
        flexDirection:'row'
      }}
    >
      <Image
        source={IMAGE.MYCOURSES4}
        style={{ width: 60, height: 60 }}
      />
      <View>
     
      <Text style={{fontSize:17, fontWeight:'bold', marginHorizontal:15}}>CRM Management</Text>
      <Text style={{fontSize:14, color:'grey', marginHorizontal:15}}>3hrs 20mins</Text>
       
    <Progress.Bar style={{marginHorizontal:15, marginVertical:5}} progress={0.88} width={200} />
    </View>
    
    </View>
   
  </TouchableOpacity>
  <TouchableOpacity>
    
    <View
      style={{
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: "#fff",
        backgroundColor:'#fff',
        borderRadius: 10,
        padding: 15,
        marginHorizontal:20,
        marginVertical:15,
        display:'flex',
        flexDirection:'row'
      }}
    >
      <Image
        source={IMAGE.MYCOURSES5}
        style={{ width: 60, height: 60 }}
      />
      <View>
     
      <Text style={{fontSize:17, fontWeight:'bold', marginHorizontal:15}}>Flutter Mobile Apps</Text>
      <Text style={{fontSize:14, color:'grey', marginHorizontal:15}}>4hrs 50mins</Text>
       
    <Progress.Bar style={{marginHorizontal:15, marginVertical:5}} progress={0.95} width={200} />
    </View>
    
    </View>
   
  </TouchableOpacity>
  <TouchableOpacity>
    
    <View
      style={{
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: "#fff",
        backgroundColor:'#fff',
        borderRadius: 10,
        padding: 15,
        marginHorizontal:20,
        display:'flex',
        flexDirection:'row'
      }}
    >
      <Image
        source={IMAGE.MYCOURSES6}
        style={{ width: 60, height: 60 }}
      />
      <View>
     
      <Text style={{fontSize:17, fontWeight:'bold', marginHorizontal:15}}>3D Icons Set Blender</Text>
      <Text style={{fontSize:14, color:'grey', marginHorizontal:15}}>2hrs 45mins</Text>
       
    <Progress.Bar style={{marginHorizontal:15, marginVertical:5}} progress={0.85} width={200} />
    </View>
    
    </View>
   
  </TouchableOpacity>

  </ScrollView>
  )
}

const initialLayout = { width: Dimensions.get('window').width };


function MyCoursesPage({ navigation }) { 
  const [index, setIndex] = React.useState(0);
  const [routes] = React.useState([
    { key: 'first', title: 'Ongoing' },  
    { key: 'second', title: 'Completed' },    
  ]); 
     
  const renderScene = SceneMap({ 
    first: FirstRoute,  
    second: SecondRoute,
  });



  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor:'#f7f7f7' }}>
     
      <CustomHeader title="My Courses" isHome={true} navigation={navigation} />
        
      <View style={{ 
        flexDirection: "row", 
        justifyContent: "flex-end",
        marginTop:-35
      }}>
         <TouchableOpacity >          
      <Image source={IMAGE.MYCOURSES1} style={{width: 22, height:22}}/>
      </TouchableOpacity>           
      <TouchableOpacity >           
      <Image source={IMAGE.MYCOURSES2} style={{width: 22, height:22, marginHorizontal:15}}/>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      
     
      <TabView
      navigationState={{ index, routes }}
      renderTabBar={props => (
        <TabBar
          {...props}
          renderLabel={({ route, color }) => (
            <Text style={{ color: '#335ef7', fontWeight:'bold', margin: 8 }}>
              {route.title} 
            </Text>
          )}
          style={{backgroundColor: 'white'}}
        />
      )}
      renderScene={renderScene}  
      onIndexChange={setIndex}   
      initialLayout={initialLayout} 
      style={styles.container}
    />
     
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

export default MyCoursesPage;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    marginTop: StatusBar.currentHeight,
  },
  scene: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});
```

and my stack navigator code is below

```
import React from "react";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import MyCoursesPage from "../pages/MyCourses/MyCoursesPage";
import MyCoursesPage2 from "../pages/MyCourses/MyCoursesPage2"
import MyCoursesDetailsPage from "../pages/MyCourses/MyCoursesDetailsPage";
import Coursedetailscreen from "../pages/MyCourses/Coursedetailscreen";

const StackSetting = createStackNavigator();

function MyCoursesStackNavigator() {
  return (
    <StackSetting.Navigator initialRouteName="MyCoursesPage" screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
      <StackSetting.Screen name="MyCoursesPage" component={MyCoursesPage} />
      <StackSetting.Screen name="MyCoursesPage2" component={MyCoursesPage2} />
      <StackSetting.Screen name="MyCoursesDetailsPage" component={MyCoursesDetailsPage} />
      <StackSetting.Screen name="Coursedetailscreen" component={Coursedetailscreen} />
    </StackSetting.Navigator>
  );
}

export default MyCoursesStackNavigator;
```

```
import React from "react";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import MyCoursesPage from "../pages/MyCourses/MyCoursesPage";
import MyCoursesPage2 from "../pages/MyCourses/MyCoursesPage2"
import MyCoursesDetailsPage from "../pages/MyCourses/MyCoursesDetailsPage";
import Coursedetailscreen from "../pages/MyCourses/Coursedetailscreen";

const StackSetting = createStackNavigator();

function MyCoursesStackNavigator() {
  return (
    <StackSetting.Navigator initialRouteName="MyCoursesPage" screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
      <StackSetting.Screen name="MyCoursesPage" component={MyCoursesPage} />
      <StackSetting.Screen name="MyCoursesPage2" component={MyCoursesPage2} />
      <StackSetting.Screen name="MyCoursesDetailsPage" component={MyCoursesDetailsPage} />
      <StackSetting.Screen name="Coursedetailscreen" component={Coursedetailscreen} />
    </StackSetting.Navigator>
  );
}

export default MyCoursesStackNavigator;
```

The only problem is that when I am using onpress in scope of return it is working but I want to use it on top because of the react native tab view code is there please help me

I am only expecting there is no other issue in this code but only onpress is not working outside of the return scope

Comment: can you please add your code here https://snack.expo.dev/

Comment: this is a big project that's why i can't upload becuase It has many files